# How to cache git personal token credentials

Tags: git

`git` asks for a personal token for pulling latest changes, but it keeps asking for every repository.

How to cache the personal token so that "git pull" doesn't ask for this every time?

We tried git credential helper `cache`, but its not effective

Answer (score 0):

Check your `git config credential.helper` output.

The normal way to cache credentials, in a cross-platform way, is by using the `manager-core`: Microsoft [GCM Git Credentials Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core)

You can [install it on your platform](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#download-and-install), and make a new `git pull`: it will prompt for your credentials (use a token as a password), and cache them.